# How to attach database in SQL Server 2008 R2 without index.idx file

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, database-indexes

I have a database test (`test.mdf`, `test_ldf.log` and `test_idx.idx`). By mistake I deleted the `test_idx.idx` file and due to file was over 20 GB.

I have used all type of recovery software but can't find the file.

Unfortunately that database is not backed up, and now SQL Server 2008 R2 doesn't let me attach the database.

Is there any way to attach the database `test.mdf` file without index file?

Error when I try to attach database:

> Unable to open the physical file ".idx". Operating system error 2: "2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)

Comment: Are you using Snapshot replication?

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry i am dont know about the snapshot replication. i am trying to attach the databse using SQL server GUI interface. I never used Snapshot publication, i just tried but ofcourse it doesnt show me  the DB because its not attached...:(

Comment: I have never heard of files with .idx extension being used in SQL Server, so I searched the internet the only thing that comes up for "idx" files is "Snapshot Replication". I suggest you talk to your DBA regarding this.

Comment: I've never heard of idx file either. What was in it? Maybe it was just a NDF fiel with a .idx extension

Comment: Maybe. Just maybe. Somebody created second data file just to keep indexes and changed extension to `idx`. Very crazy idea. If it is true, that person is sick.

Comment: Thats table is clustered indexes: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190197(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: If you created clustered indexes in that file it means you deleted your data. In case you want to restore whatever is left in your `mdf` file it might cost you $10K-@20K-$30K or more. Are these data really cost as much?

Answer (score 0):

1. create a dummy database (name is not important) with the same file structures.  ie a data file, log file and index file.
2. take the index file and database offline like so:

   alter database <dbname> modify file(name = '<name of your index file>', offline)

   alter database <dbname> set offline

You'll not be able to recover the offline file (to my knowledge) so dont give it the same logical name as your original file - you'll see why in a moment.

3. now overwrite the dummy database files with what you have left of your broken database (obviously keep the copies somewhere safe!)
4. bring the database back online

   alter database <dbname> set online

At this point your data should be accessible.

5. create new filegroup/file with the same logical names as your original and rebuild indexes

Good Luck!

Comment: @expertcoder1123 - How did you get on?  Did my answer help resolve the problem?